# Can not add Quote field into Quote Product form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

We all know that there is 1:N relation between `quote` and `quote product`.
And there is a field in `quote product` named `quoteid`, I mean
[image: this]
Now I want to code a `JavaScript` in `Quote Product` Form that need Quote ID.
I want to put `quoteid` field (that is a reference to the primary related quote) into the form.
But I can not see this field(`quoteid`) in the form fields, 
like [image: this]
The `quoteid` field is not listed in the All fields, and If I want to create new lookup field, It creates new 1:N relation and I dont want this.
I tried another way to get  Quote Id by calling a REST, in this way :

The quoteid field is not listed in the All fields, and If I want to create new lookup field, It creates new 1:N relation and I dont want this.
I tried another way to get  Quote Id by calling a REST, in this way :

```
var quoteProductGUID=Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
var firstReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
firstReq.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + 
"/XRMService/2011/OrganizationData.svc /QuoteDetailSet(guid'"+quoteProductGUID+"')?$select=QuoteId", true);

firstReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
firstReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;    charset=utf-8");
firstReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState === 4) {
    this.onreadystatechange = null;
    if (this.status === 200) {
        var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText).d;
        var quoteId = result.QuoteId;
        quoteId=quoteId.Id;

    } else {
        alert(this.statusText);
    }
   }
 };
firstReq.send();
}
```

But it needs the quote product Id and when It has not created yet, It can not get the quote product Id.
So the question is how can I display quoteid field that already exist in the form.